# NGINX too long location (massive?)

Tags: nginx, location, massive

NGINX

Have a locations like:

```
location ~ "^\/(place1|place2|...|place50)\/(service1|service2|...|service80)\-(else1|else2|...|else90)\/"
{...}

location ~ "^\/(word1|word2|...|word70)\/(place1|place2|...|place50)\-(else1|else2|...|else90)\/"
{...}

location ~ "^\/..."
```

The problem is there are a lot of places & services & words & else. So locations are awfully long strings. Is it possible to make them shorter? Maybe massive of places and massive of services and so on? Or something? Who has some experience?

examples of URI i want to match

```
/place23/service17-else87/
```

or

```
/world33/place42-else15/
```

and any combinations

For each location we are going to use set of rules. In order to use cache and unload our Apache

```
        #proxy_cache start
        set $do_not_cache 0;
        # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
        if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $do_not_cache 1;
        }
        if ($query_string != "") {
            set $do_not_cache 1;
        }
        # Don't use the cache for logged in users or REBent commenters
        if ($http_cookie ~* "wordpress_logged_in|bn_my_logged") {
            set $do_not_cache 1;
        }
        if ($args ~* (show) ) {
            set $do_not_cache 1;
        }
        ssi_types "*";
        ssi on;
        if ($do_not_cache = 0) {
            set $memcached_key "SMREG|$request_uri";
            memcached_pass memc_server;
            ssi on;
        }
```

Comment: can you give examples of the URI's you want to match

Comment: have just added examples

Comment: Why are you handling these on the web server level, not the application level ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in location blocks to make them match multiple things, rather than listing them all by hand.

e.g.

```
location ~* ^/world(\d{1,2})/place(\d{1,2})-else(\d{1,2})/ {

    set $originalURI  $uri;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING  q=$originalURI&world=$1&place=$2&else=$3;
    # or however you're passing it to your web server.
}
```

However as Mohammad AbuShady implied, what you're doing seems quite dumb.

You should be letting your application do the routing, and deciding whether things can be cached or not, and then using something that is actually designed to cache web pages e.g. [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/), rather than trying to force application logic into Nginx.